# How to save words to a new list?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, if-statement

For each word in words, add ‘d’ to the end of the word if the word ends in “e” to make it past tense. Otherwise, add ‘ed’ to make it past tense. Save these past tense words to a list called past_tense.

```
words = ["adopt", "bake", "beam", "confide", "grill", "plant", "time", "wave", "wish"]

for i in words:
if i[len(i)-1] == "e":
    print(i+"d")
else:
    print(i+"ed")
```

I created the words but I cannot put them into a list. So what is the correct way of approach to this problem

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried to `put them into a list.`

Comment: string are immutable,you canot modify exisitng one

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty list, then append the modified words to it instead of just printing them:

```
past_tense = []  # this is your list to collect the past tense verbs

for word in words:
    if word.endswith("e"):
        past_tense.append(word + "d")
    else:
        past_tense.append(word + "ed")
```

I renamed your loop variable to something more semantically appropriate since `i` usually indicates an index.

If you want to go a little more fancy, you can do this in one line, using a list comprehension:

```
past_tense = [word + ("d" if word.endswith("e") else "ed") for word in words]
```

##### Some docs to read:

- [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)
- [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)
- [negative list index](https://www.askpython.com/python/list/negative-indexing)

Comment: yeah I missed that append thing in the lists

Comment: "no English infinitives that end in two "e" - this is a quite an assumption: to see, to flee and pardon me, to pee ;)

Comment: apart from that, `endswith` looks better than `word[-1] == `.

Comment: @gog For the double "e", I -- well -- *agree*.

Comment: The "more fancy" one is wrong. Btw another fancy: `word.removesuffix('e') + 'ed'`

Comment: @KellyBundy fixed the scoping.  `removeSuffix` I was unaware of. Gotta read Python version changelogs as bedtime stories or something =)

Comment: Yeah, that one is even fairly old by now, although rarely used. Another: `word + "ed"[word.endswith("e"):]`

Comment: That works, too. Has an additional negation and creates a longer intermediate string than mine, though.

Comment: Oh, I am stupid. I was confused by the line break. Of course yours is fine and much better

Comment: Wait, I think yours actually didn't even work (not sure, as you deleted it).

Answer (score 1):

1st way

```
for i, j in enumerate(words.copy()):
     if j[len(j) - 1] == 'e':
         words.remove(j)
         words.insert(i, j+"d")
     else:
         words.remove(j)
         words.insert(i,  j+'ed')
```

second way

```
words = [j + 'ed' if j[len(j) - 1] != 'e' else j + 'd' for i, j in enumerate(words.copy())]
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you're doing great. What you need to do is to create another list, and use the `append` method. See more list/tuple methods [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_list.asp)

```
words = ["adopt", "bake", "beam", "confide", "grill", "plant", "time", "wave", "wish"]

output = []

for i in words:
  if i[len(i)-1] == "e":
    output.append(i+"d")
  else:
    output.append(i+"ed")
```

Please accept my answer if this helped!